# Perl Regex: Does the at sign @ need to be escaped?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm unable to determine why my regex is failing. Here is my code:

```
my $email = "rise@dawn.com";
my ($found) = $email =~ /(rise@dawn\.com)/;
print "Found: $found";
```

This results in the output:

```
C:\scripts\perl\sandbox>regex.pl
Found: rise.com
```

If I escape the @ sign, then I get no output at all:

```
my $email = "rise@dawn.com";
my ($found) = $email =~ /(rise\@dawn\.com)/;
print "Found: $found";

C:\scripts\perl\sandbox>regex.pl
Found:
```

Could someone please enlighten me as to my errors.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your scripts!

It would warn you that there is an undeclared global variable `@dawn`. Arrays can be interpolated into double quoted strings as well, so you need

```
my $email = "rise\@dawn.com";
my ($found) = $email =~ /(rise\@dawn\.com)/;
print "Found: $found";
```

Comment: When I'm reading text from a file, is that considered as "single quoted" string?

Comment: Yes. Data isn't evaluated as Perl code unless you specifically request it. Otherwise, Perl would have horrendous security issues. The interpolation rules only apply to string literals in your script.

Comment: If you're using data from a file, use `quotemeta` to escape the meta-character of regular expressions. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

Answer (score 9):

in your declaration of `$email` you are interpolating `@dawn`
This is due to quoting.

To avoid any hassle, just use single quotes like this:

```
my $email = 'rise@dawn.com';
my ($found) = $email =~ /(rise\@dawn\.com)/;
print "Found: $found";
```

Comment: Ah, does "interpolate" mean "evaluate a meaning"?

Comment: interpolate, translate, evaluate, you name it. Basically i was meaning to say, that inside double-quoted strings perl will try to find variables ($, %, @ ..) and fill in their contents.

Answer (score 6):

In a double-quoted string or regex in Perl, an `@` followed by a word is treated as the name of an array whose values are to be inserted, space-separated, into the string or regex at that position, similar to handling of `"scalar $variables in strings"`.  You thus need to escape the `@` in both `$email` *and* the regex in order for your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, according to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace):

> If single quotes are used s''', then the regex and replacement are treated as single-quoted strings.

So the following will work, too:

```
my $email = q{rise@dawn.com};
my ($found) = $email =~ m'(rise@dawn\.com)';
print "Found: $found";
```

I'd typically use `\Q...\E` to deal with that literal period, BTW, but I didn't want to obscure the point I was trying to make.